# What is the difference between creating a struct variable immediately and creating a variable later?

Tags: c, struct

Say you have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
};
```

Now if I wanted to have a struct variable of type Point, I could do this:

```
struct Point p1 = {5, 5};
```

This works just fine. However, I have seen that you can also create struct variables like this:

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
} p2;
```

If I now try to assign a value to my struct variable `p2`, like this:

```
p2 = {6, 6};
```

I get an error. Why is that the case?

Comment: Because assignment is not initialization. Take differently: because the C standard says so.

Comment: Structure's can be initialized only at the time of declaration but not afterwards.

Comment: @user2426316, you didn't vote for a single answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only works for initialization:

```
Point p1 = {5, 5}; // Ok
```

while it doesn't for declaration + assignment:

```
Point p2;
p2 = {5, 5}; // Error
```

Comment: No `typedef` is shown in the question, and this is C, not C++, so the declaration of `struct Point` does not create a type named `Point`. You must use `struct Point`.

Answer (score 0):

[Correct form:](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/initialization.html)

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
} p2 = {5,5};
```

Also, I thought this was interesting from the linked page:

```
struct s{
      int a;
      struct ss{
              int c;
              char d;
      }e;
}x[] = {
      {1, {2, 'a'}},
      {3, {4, 'b'}}
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitions and assignments require different syntaxes. They are the same for simple types (`int x = 5;` and `x = 5;`), but they are different for compound types.

In C 1999 and later, you can assign values for compound types using “compound literals” (which are not actually literals):

```
p2 = (struct Point) { 5, 5 };
```

Answer (score 0):

`struct Point p1 = {5, 5};` creates a variable `p1` assigned to given values in square brackets.  Where as `p2 = {6, 6};` looks similar to above case but its just an assignment expression to the LHS which doesn't have any meaning.

However in `C99`, `p2 = (struct Point) {6, 6};` this makes RHS a valid expression assignment.

Comment: `(struct Point) {6, 6}` is a compound literal, not a cast.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ok. Syntactically they look like cast but really not.